# Python launcher couldn't start

Tags: python

everyone!
My problem is that python launcher py can't start, and the cmd can't find the command.
[image]

'py' is either an internal or external command or a running program or batch file.

Comment: This is going to get voted down. You need to provide more details, like what system your on, what exactly you are doing

Comment: Like @Joe said, also provide what you tried. Did you check if python is in your path, if `py` is in your path/directory/whatever

Comment: My system is Windows10. I have checked python in my path, it's correct.I have installed python 2.7.13 and python 3.6.3, I want to specify the version of python, in order to install pip package. For example `py -2 -m pip install Django`

Answer (score 1):

Going from the screenshot, it seems like you are using windows command line. The first thing you can try is using the full python command

```
C:\>python
```

But that is assuming that the install is correctly configured with correct environment paths. If the first command did not work, you can temporarily set the environment path and start python with these:

```
C:\>set PATH=C:\Program Files\Python 3.6;%PATH%
C:\>set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib
C:\>python
```

See more information on the official python documentation https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html

Comment: The path of python is correct. But py.exe couldn't execute rightly.